Pipe .exe output to text file
I have a utility exe which opens a new window when I run the exe directly or through powershell.
How do I pipe its output to a text file?
I have used
utility.exe > textino.txt 

But it creates a blank text file.

So, even in commandline, like Powershell, it tries to open a new window? That sounds weird. What do you see when you launch it in a regular command prompt?

Does utility.exe >> textino.txt 2>&1 give you any different non-blank results?

Hello, this lacks details and is unanswerable accurately. Is there any standard output from the app? What app is it? What is the expected result?

Unless the executable presents text output, you cannot.

You can't : A graphical program does not have textual output, so there
is nothing to pipe.
The most you can do, if it's possible to do with this program, is to
copy-paste text from the window of the program into a text file.
If the program displays the text, but it doesn't let you copy it, you
may still convert the displayed graphical text to real text by using
an OCR program. My favorite is
Capture2Text.

A Windows application can return an exit code, an integer value. That exit code is stored in a variable, errorlevel.
To capture that return value, see the following batch file example using start /wait:
echo off
start /wait "myapp" "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
pause

If one closes Notepad normally, the returned value is 0 (zero). If one kills Notepad form Task Manager, an error level of 1 is returned. That value could be piped to a text file.
